# Upon finishing a multiprocessing pool in Python, is there a way to combine global variables across all sub-processes?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I figure one solution could be to use a shared memory resource to access the same variables across all sub-processes, but I really only care about the final sum once all processes are finished. Is there a straightforward way to iterate across the finished processes and access specific variables in each one?

Here's a modified snippet of the multiprocessing code:

```
pool = Pool(cpu_count())
results = list(tqdm.tqdm(pool.imap_unordered(Article.analyze_pool, articles), total=len(articles)))
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Comment: Can you share part the multiprocessing part of the code?

Comment: Yes please see the updated question

Comment: This isn't really the point of using a Pool. Pool processes are meant to be indistinguishable and even expandable with ``maxtasksperchild``. Is "sum all process' global value" really the problem you need to solve, or merely how far you have come trying to solve your actual problem?

Comment: `return` the variables you need from `Article.analyze_pool` and they will be in the `results` list.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi all of my processes are indistinguishable and independent. The function I am calling is CPU intensive and running it in parallel over the set of inputs results in drastic speedups. I merely want to track the calls to a particular function across all subprocesses for logging purposes.

Comment: It's fine if you want to stick to the initial question (especially now that you have an answer). However, "track the calls to a particular function across all subprocesses" is a different thing than "sum global variables across all sub-processes" – answer for the latter won't be optimal to do the former.

Answer (score 0):

You can return the values you want to access from the `Article.analyze_pool` function and they will be available in `results`. Since you are using `imap_unordered()` they will be in a different order than `articles`, watch out for that. You can either also return an identifier of `Article` from `Article.analyze_pool` or use the ordered equivalent `imap()`.